# Can´t access my public folder from css file in React App

Tags: css, reactjs, node-modules, postcss, public-folders

I'm receiving the following error everytime I try to access a file in my public folders.

```
./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
Error: Can't resolve '/assets/fonts/PlantinMTProRg.woff' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\NewPage\webpage\src'
```

As you can see, I'm trying to call a font from my index.css, which is inside my src folder.

I call it as it follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'PlantinMTPro';
  src: local('plantin_mt_pro'), url(/assets/fonts/PlantinMTProRg.woff) format('truetype');
}
```

But no luck so far. Having the same issue for images.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In your index.html you must link your index.css from the public directory

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%DIR%/NewPage/webpage/src/index.css">
```

From there, you need to figure out the right url to reach your font family, which you said was in your src file.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'PlantinMTPro';
  src: local('plantin_mt_pro'), url(/assets/fonts/PlantinMTProRg.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Also, I notice you used format of truetype. Only use that if you're importing a .ttf file. Use `format('woff')` in this scenario.

You may need to add some changes here if you're trying to support multiple browsers

Comment: Hey there. The thing is, public folder is not in my current directory. My current directory is src folder, and usually when I try to call public I just go "/ ".

But this error never ocurred to me before.

Comment: Right, but "index.css" is not in the public folder, the fonts are, inside an assets folder.

Comment: Just include the fonts in your project and import them. That's the best solution

Comment: Thanks, but not what I'm looking for. Need to keep fonts and images out of the final build. But thank you!

Comment: Can you just try and change the format('truetype') to format('woff')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223761/discussion-between-berkobienb-and-jose-peres).